# Is there a more elegant way to compute the determinant of this Dirac-space matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, dirac-matrices

Consider the Dirac-space matrix

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
D =A+\gamma^0\gamma^jB_j+\gamma^0C
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
(A+C)I_2 & \sigma^jB_j \\
\sigma^jB_j & (A-C)I_2
\end{pmatrix},
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

where $A$,$(B_j)_{j=1,2,3},C$ are complex numbers, $\sigma^j$ are the Pauli matrices, and the summation convention is used. We have used the Weyl representation of the gamma matrices.

I was able to show

$$\det D=\left(A^2-C^2-|B|^2\right)^2$$

by direct computation. That is, I multiplied out the nine nonzero terms that arise in the [Leibniz determinant formula](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Leibniz_formula_for_determinants) for a $4\times 4$ matrix, taking into account the signs of the permutations, and then did a some algebra to arrive at the above. This process is a bit messy, and the result that comes out is very nice, especially given the appearance of $|B|^2$ and no final products of $B$'s with $A$'s (before the overall square is taken).

So I suspect there is a more elegant way to compute this determinant that shows more directly why such a simple result appears. Perhaps it leverages the tensor-product forms of the gamma matrices $\gamma^0=\sigma^3\otimes I_2,\gamma^0\gamma^j=\sigma^1\otimes \sigma^j$, and properties of the Pauli matrices. Can anyone provide such a method?

**Edit:** If we treat the original matrix like a $2\times 2$, as written above, and take the determinant, then the result would be $A^2-C^2-|B|^2$, after taking properties of the Pauli matrices into account. The true result is just the square of this, so one approach for a more elegant solution would be to justify treating the matrix as a $2\times 2$ in this way and then taking the square.

---

By the way, this computation appears when calculating the free energy of a Fermion field at finite chemical potential in thermal QFT. See Kapusta Eqs. (2.93) and (2.94), where this matrix appears with $A\to (-i\omega_n+\mu)$, $B_j\to -p_j$, and $C\to-m$.

Comment: Wikipedia: [Block matrix determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_matrix_determinant)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be an even better way than the following, but this is already better than multiplying out nine terms in a $4 \times 4$ matrix and keeping track of permutation signs.

Defining

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
D =
\begin{pmatrix}
(A+C)I_2 & \sigma^jB_j \\
\sigma^jB_j & (A-C)I_2
\end{pmatrix},
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

we note that $D_{12}$ and $D_{22}$ commute, since $D_{22}$ is proportional to the identity matrix $I_2$.

It then follows (as per the comment by @Ghoster) that $\det(D) = \det(D_{11}D_{22} - D_{12}D_{21})$ (see also ref [1]).

The argument of the determinant on the right of this expression can be seen by inspection to be

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
(A^2 -C^2)I_2 - (\sigma^j B_j)^2.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Next we notice that

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\sigma^j B_j =
\begin{pmatrix}
B_3  & B_1 - iB_2 \\
B_1 + iB_2 & -B_3
\end{pmatrix},
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

which squares to

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\begin{pmatrix}
B_1^2 + B_2^2 + B_3^2  & 0 \\
0 & B_1^2 + B_2^2 + B_3^2
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

The result follows immediately (although I find the notation $|B|$ a bit ambiguous in this context - are the $B_j$ truly meant to be complex numbers or do I misunderstand?).

Note that we didn't need to make use of any of the properties of the Dirac gamma matrices, and that the problem was essentially reduced to a $2 \times 2$ one.

**References**

[1] Silvester, J. (2000). Determinants of block matrices. The Mathematical Gazette, 84(501), 460-467. doi:10.2307/3620776

Comment: This is definitely an improvement!

Comment: @WillG Great! I've fleshed it out a bit more